# How to decide cost to launch ethereum smart contract on MainNet

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, web3js

I have written and launched a smart contract of solidity in ropsten network. And it is working well. Now I want to launch that on main net. I know few things like 
 
1- Cost to launch depends on the opcodes. Well I have written about 50 lines of smart contract and when seeing opcodes its too large. It is tedious to calculate the approximate cost to launch on main net seeing opcodes. 
2 - There is a function in web3js named **estimateGas**. But it used for only transaction not for launching contract. 
3 - There is something like gasPrice and maxGasAmmount which can be used by a miner. Also gasPrice varies from 2 gwei to n gwei. 
4 - It also depends upon the variables used in constructor.

I have also refered to this website https://ethgasstation.info/index.php and https://www.myetherwallet.com but couldn't get much info. What can be the gas price and max gas price which can be kept for an ideal contract having some basic functionalities like transfer tokens, check balance, maintain owner and transfer owner etc.
I want to make around 10 billion tokens on main net. Is it possible? If yes what can be the approximate cost for that considering March 2018 for that.  I don't mind waiting for 5-15 minutes to launch the contract.

Answer (score 2):

`estimateGas` will tell you exactly how much gas you need, but pretty much any tool you use to deploy will call that for you. (Yes, that's for estimating the gas usage of a transaction, but deploying a contract *is* a transaction.)

You already launched to Ropsten, so presumably you managed to use a sensible gas amount then. Do whatever you did to deploy that time.

For the gas price, https://ethgasstation.info/ is indeed a good resource. Right now 2 gwei looks good if you're not in a hurry.